# Java heap space error in creation possible symbol

Tags: java, arrays, out-of-memory, stringbuilder

I have written a function that throws a Java heap space error at line `symbols.append(c)`

```
public static StringBuilder createPossibleSymbols(int possibleSymbols) {
    StringBuilder symbols = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        symbols.append((char) (i + '0'));
    }
    if (possibleSymbols == 10) {
        return symbols;
    }
    for (char c = 'a'; c <= (c + possibleSymbols - 10); c++) {
        symbols.append(c);
    }
    return symbols;
}
```

This function is used to create a list of possible symbols that will be used to generate a random code. The user has to input how many possible symbols there will be - if he inputs 10, the code will be generated with random numbers 0-9, if he inputs 16, the code will contain numbers 0-9 and lowercase latin letters a-f, but each symbol in the code has to be unique, which is why I used `StringBuilder` (to remove a char that has just been added to the code). I have no idea how to rewrite this function to make it work.

Comment: `c <= (c + possibleSymbols - 10)` would always be true for values of `possibleSymbols` >= 10, thus an infinite loop.

Comment: thanks, after changing c (in the condition) to 'a' it works as intented.

Comment: @gierol don't forget to accept answer if it has solved your problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
static char START_CHAR = 'a';
public static StringBuilder createPossibleSymbols(int possibleSymbols) {
    StringBuilder symbols = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < Math.min(possibleSymbols, 10); i++) {
        symbols.append((char) (i + '0'));
    }
    if (possibleSymbols <= 10) {
        return symbols;
    }
    int length = (int) START_CHAR + possibleSymbols - 10;
    for (char c = START_CHAR; c < length; c++) {
        symbols.append(c);
    }
    return symbols;
}
```

Output (for ex. 31):

```
0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstu
```